# Using numpy with rospy tutorial - no module found

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/numpy) tutorial. In Step 3, when I tried to run the listener, it threw following error:

> ~/catkin_ws/src/numpy_tutorial$ rosrun
> numpy_tutorial numpy_listener.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/home/user/catkin_ws/src/numpy_tutorial/scripts/numpy_listener.py",
> line 7, in 
> from rospy.numpy_pkg import numpy_msg ImportError: No module named
> numpy_pkg

I tried to get the module and provide it to ros but to vain. Can anyone help me fix this, please?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232710/using-numpy-with-rospy-tutorial---no-module-found/) by [achus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26531/achus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There could be many reasons.

- Make sure you have numpy installed.
  But it should be already.
- Make sure you did in your
  *catking_workspace* `catkin_make`
- Make sure you did `source devel/setup.bash` in every terminal
  where you want to use rosrun or etc.
- Make sure **roscore** is running

---

Originally posted by [robopo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26642/robopo/) with karma: 72 on 2016-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [achus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26531/achus/) on 2016-04-24**:
Thanks for the reply. Those possibilities had already been ruled out. The issue was that I kept my script file numpy_listener.py in numpy_tutorials/scripts directory. Till then I believed that all .py scripts go in /scripts while all .cpp files go in /src. My bad! Thanks again.